# Centered background extending to the edge of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I don't how to do background which extend and will be centered

now I have something like this:

```
body {
    background: url(tlo.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

It is centered and it have constant size....

I want that it will be just proportionally expanded......

I need to **keep the proportions**

thanks!

**OK i have solution! :)**

```
body {
    background-image: url(tlo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: no no, i want to keep the proportions!! all this question is how to to stretch or scale... i want it but i want too keep the proportions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 body {
        background: url(tlo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: When i resize width, height resize too.. i want to keep the proportions

Answer (score 0):

i think `background-size:` may help you..

```
 body {
        background: url(tlo.jpg) no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```

it will take 100% width of body's total width and 100% height of body's total height...